# Qt SqLite how to switch to multithread mode?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I use Sqlite in QT (serialized mode) default. Multiple threads write to different recording bases.
Without reading.
Sqlite documentation says that you can switch to MULTITHREAD mode, passing the parameters when opening. Parameter: SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX.
The problem is how to do this in Qt? Transfer option so??? `m_db.setConnectOptions("SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX");` ???

```
QString connection = QString(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
if (QSqlDatabase::contains(connection)) {
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::cloneDatabase(m_db, connection);
}
else {
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", connection);
    m_db.setDatabaseName(basename);


    m_db.setConnectOptions(“SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX"); // will work????
}
```

Comment: Not in the documented list of connection option. Source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions

Comment: What are the options? Compiling sqlite with the necessary parameters?

Comment: I came here searching for help with crashes with Qt5 SQLite as soon as multiple threads were running. After reading @RichardCritten 's comment & link, I wrapped all our database calls (from before any QSqlQuery or transaction) in a mutex.  The problem went away immediately!  So maybe our .deb of the qt5-sqlite driver was certainly not compiled in "SERIALIZED" mode.  But there seems to be no documented way of switching at runtime when using the Qt5 version either.